# ViewModelProviders.of(activity) error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, viewmodel

I have no idea what to do anymore but ask here.
When i try to access the ViewModel from a fragment attached to an activity:

---

`private val userViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(UserProfileViewModel::class.java) }`
i get an error for "activity" saying "Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but FragmentActivity was expected"

every example i've seen so far is using it this way and i just can't get it to work.
Not sure if this is deprecated and i should just give up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that `activity` can be null when the viewmodel is lazy loaded, which means the type of activity is `FragmentActivity?` instead of the required `FragmentActivity`.

The ViewModel Initialization is usually not done with a delegate, but in a lifecycle method, where you are sure you are attached to an activity, like in onViewCreated() or onActivityCreated().

There you can safely use:

```
userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(UserProfileViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: When you are sure that the userViewModel is only accessed in places, where your fragment is attached to an activity, you cal also alter your code to: private val userViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(UserProfileViewModel::class.java) }